# Spring Security Login via ajax from domain with different port

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am developing a web service including three web servers with spring boot:
1. localhost:8080 - ui 
2. localhost:9999 - uaa (authserver)
3. localhost:9000 - ressource

I took this example repository https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2 and modified it with a UserDetailsService and a custom authenticationSuccessHandler / authenticationFailureHandler for the login process.

I would like to have my login page at the localhost:8080 and make a ajax / angularjs request to the localhost:9999 to login. This works fine but I do not get the jsessionid issued by the uaa server in the response header and therefore I can not make any secured requests.
[image: log from the authserver as the user login is successful]
How do I have to modify my authserver to send the jsessionid as a cookie back to my ui server?

This is the response header, if I would have the template on the authserver like the example repository and make the request:
[image]

And this is the response header, if I make the request by the localhost:8080 to the authserver:
[image]

**Source Code:**

-Authserver (localhost:9999)

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "foobar".toCharArray())
                .getKeyPair("test");
        converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        endpoints
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("acme").secret("acmesecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password")
                .scopes("openid")
                .autoApprove(true);
        // @formatter:on
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(-20)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    public WebSecurityConfig(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/signup", "/forgotPassword", "/user/updatePassword**", "/user/registration", "/user/registrationConfirm**", "/user/resendRegistrationToken**", "/user/resetPassword**", "/user/changePassword**", "/user/savePassword").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler).failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler).permitAll()
            .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login**", "/signup", "/forgotPassword", "/user/updatePassword**", "/user/registration", "/user/registrationConfirm**", "/user/resendRegistrationToken**", "/user/resetPassword**", "/user/changePassword**", "/user/savePassword", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access");
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    //Beans

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
}

@Component
public class RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }
}

@Component
public class RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}

@Component
public class RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

-ui-Server (localhost:8080)

```
@Configuration
@Order(-20)
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        http
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("XSRF-TOKEN").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/",
                    "/signin",
                    "/uaa/login",
                    "/pix/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        //@formatter:on
    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080

debug: true

spring:
  aop:
    proxy-target-class: true


security:
  user:
    password: none
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
      clientId: acme
      clientSecret: acmesecret
    resource:
      jwt:
        keyValue: |
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnGp/Q5lh0P8nPL21oMMrt2RrkT9AW5jgYwLfSUnJVc9G6uR3cXRRDCjHqWU5WYwivcF180A6CWp/ireQFFBNowgc5XaA0kPpzEtgsA5YsNX7iSnUibB004iBTfU9hZ2Rbsc8cWqynT0RyN4TP1RYVSeVKvMQk4GT1r7JCEC+TNu1ELmbNwMQyzKjsfBXyIOCFU/E94ktvsTZUHF4Oq44DBylCDsS1k7/sfZC2G5EU7Oz0mhG8+Uz6MSEQHtoIi6mc8u64Rwi3Z3tscuWG2ShtsUFuNSAFNkY7LkLn+/hxLCu2bNISMaESa8dG22CIMuIeRLVcAmEWEWH5EEforTg+QIDAQAB
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

zuul:
  routes:
    resource:
      path: /resource/**
      url: http://localhost:9000/resource
    user:
      path: /uaa/**
      url: http://localhost:9999/uaa

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

signin.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('loginUser').controller('LoginViewController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/uaa/login',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
                var str = [];
                for(var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                return str.join("&");
            },
            data: {"username": $scope.user.username, "password": $scope.user.password}
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
        });
    }
});

angular.module('loginUser').run(function run($http, $cookies){
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = $cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'];
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
});
```

Comment: How about to use your ui server as a gateway to authserver?